# What was the hole in the wall symbolizing in "Black Box"?

Tags: plot-explanation, black-box

I just saw "Black Box" on amazon prime.
I was waiting for the movie to explain the hole in Nol's wall.
He looks at it in the first few minutes of the movie. Then we get a second look at it when the friend doctor visits him towards the middle of the movie.

But the movie ends with no explanation about why the hole was important.
Also, why is Nol's hand wrapped in bandages?
It must not be from his car accident, since the friend doctor was confused about it. I mean: the friend should expect it to be there if it was from the accident.

The bandages might be explained if it was caused by Thomas somehow punching a hole in the wall. But the movie never gave any hint about that. Or did it?

Comment: [Nolan keeps experiencing strange signs that he’s still not himself, none more shocking than a hole in the wall that suggests he’s prone to blackouts and rage spirals.](https://www.indiewire.com/2020/10/black-box-review-blumhouse-1234590875/)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkNqz0Dr3ws